# Hook for post and page load

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, pages, hooks

I need to run a function when a particular post or page is loaded. Is there any hook that lets me check whether a post is being displayed during page load ?

Comment: public or admin side/facing?

Comment: For front end. Basically I want it to trigger only when a particular single custom post type is displayed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the `wp` hook and check the `global $wp_query` object or any conditional.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse69369_special_thingy' );
function wpse69369_special_thingy()
{
    if (
        'special_cpt' === get_post_type()
        AND is_singular()
    )
        return print "Yo World!";

    return printf(
        '<p>Nothing to see here! Check the object!<br /></p><pre>%s</pre>',
        var_export( $GLOBALS['wp_query'], true )
    );
}
```

See: [`wp` in codex.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/) and [`wp` in developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/)

Comment: can you please tell me when does 'wp' hook run?

Comment: A) It runs before `after_setup_theme` and `setup_theme`, so it's only accessible for plugins B) inside `WP :: main()`, which is called from within wp-settings.php.

Comment: @kaiser Doesn't the `wp` hook fire after the `after_setup_theme` hook and right before `template_redirect` therefore making `wp` accessible by themes as well as plugins? (just to clarify?)

Answer (score 25):

Use [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) which is the action hook that fires before rendering the template;

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'hooker');
function hooker(){
    //I load just before selecting and rendering the template to screen
}
```

Comment: @PoulomiNag No problem, glad you found your answer above. Though I think one small note is that `wp` runs after the `after_theme_setup` hook, so its not just accessible by plugins, making it safe to use in themes.

Comment: I just checked and yes ; `wp` runs after `after_theme_setup`. But I need it for my plugin. So `wp` as well as `template_redirect` both work fine for me. Wish I could accept two answers here! :)

Comment: That's ok, not necessary to accept both, just wanted to clarify the order in which they fire. Making sure I'm not going crazy you know. Good luck with your plugin...

Comment: +1 for function name pun

Answer (score 1):

I've quite often used the following to load in custom meta boxes on pages (rather than custom posts).

```
    add_action('admin_init','how_we_do_it_meta');

    function how_we_do_it_meta() {

        if ( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/wp-admin/post.php' ) {

            $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'];
            $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);

            if ($template_file == 'page-how-we-do-it.php') {

                add_meta_box('how_we_do_it_who-meta', 'Who we work with...', 'how_we_do_it_who', 'page', 'normal', 'high');

                add_action('save_post', 'save_how_we_do_it_meta');

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Darronz. But I need some hook to work at the front end during a page load. Any ideas?

Comment: If you changed the above `to add_action('init', // etc)` then it'll work on the page load rather than only in the admin section.

Comment: @darronz And then you need to check `! is_admin()` inside, because the `init` hook runs on both sides.